# The semantic role of an object of a verb

Tags: objects, indirect-objects, transitivity

I've posted [a question in English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/203067/67917) as to this sentence:

> Mom made me a sandwich.

The intended meaning was "Mom made a sandwich, intending it for me."

There, I came to realize that the indirect object 'me' is not involved in the action of the verb 'made' at all.

Is my realization correct?

If so, how is it that 'me' can be an object when it has nothing to do with the verb's action at all?

Is it merely because 'me' is an *indirect* object as opposed to a *direct* object? Or is it also possible that a *direct* object is not involved in the verb's action at all?

Comment: There are several constructions in the English language which could mean something strange if understood literally. _I had John and Mary for dinner_ means that I invited them to my house for a meal, not that I ate them. _I feel like an apple_ (I would like to eat one) invites the humorous reply _You don't look like one_. So _Mom made me a sandwich_ could mean that she made me into one, but doesn't unless someone chooses to understand it that way.

Comment: How do you evaluate “involvedness?” It’s a very subjective term. You could say, for example, that “me” in your example is involved because they receive, benefit or profit from the sandwich. So if I give you an example of an unaffected direct object, you could simply say, “oh, but in my opinion the object is involved in the action.” The question is a bit vague.

Comment: @RichardZ I think simply being involved shouldn't be confused with being "involved in the action of the verb". In my example, you can't say "me" is involved in the action of the verb 'make', because "me" doesn't even have to be present when or where "Mom" makes the sandwich. And it's not even clear that "me" can eventually benefit or profit from the sandwich, because that's entirely up to context.

Comment: Ok, two questions: 1) are you familiar with the concept of semantic roles / theta roles? 2) would it be fair to paraphrase your question as: Can a direct object be a recipient or benefactor?

Comment: @RichardZ I think I know what a semantic role is, but not sure about "theta role". I'm afraid that's not my question.

Comment: Theta role is a synonym for semantic role. Same thing.

Comment: You said “‘me’ doesn’t have to present when Mom makes the sandwich”. If this is the criterion for “involvedness”, you should accept “help s.o.” as an example of what you’re looking for. In “Without realizing it, she inadvertently helped me”, “me” doesn’t have to present either.

Comment: @RichardZ Being present is important in the verb 'make' because if you're not there you're not involved in the process of making. But the same is not true with the verb 'help'. In your example, you don't have to be at the right place at the right time in order for you to be involved in the process of being helped. So I guess it's case by case.

Comment: @listeneva if Mom does the action with you in mind - as the intended beneficiary - I don't understand how you can say that has nothing to do with the action. It is the whole reason why she does the action.

Comment: What do you think about "My mom provided me with a sandwich". Here, "me" is a direct object. Do you think "me" is involved in the action? If so, how is it different from "prepared/made"?

Comment: @Minty I've repeated this many times including in the question itself. I suggest you read the question carefully. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardZ I believe the 'provide' example necessarily involves 'me' in the verb's action, because when you 'provide' someone with something, that someone actually gets to receive that something.

Comment: But that depends on the verb’s mood, embedding, modals etc. “She wanted to provide me with a sandwich, but didn’t.” She might have provided me with a sandwich, but I didn’t deserve it.” Inversely, in “She made me a sandwich. It was delicious”, I actually received the sandwich as well.

Comment: @RichardZ In your first two examples, turns out she didn't perform the act of providing. So, even though they include the verb, those examples shouldn't tell you anything about the verb's action. In your third example, it's not the first sentence but the second one that confirms that I received the sandwich. So, it shouldn't tell you anything about the first sentence.

Comment: Ok. So is it then fair to say that your criterion for involvedness is this: in the construction “She verb-ed X”, “X” must be an animate entity who *may* possibly receive or benefit from something, but *not necessarily* so, as someone could also just have had “X” in mind or intended “X” as the beneficiary?

Comment: @RichardZ Are you trying to post an answer to my question? If so, please refer to the question itself instead of trying to come up with your own question. BTW, where did you come up with the idea that 'X' must be an animate entity? Please note that the question is not about the one example in the question but about the characteristics of 'object', direct or indirect.

Comment: I told you several times: Your question is subjective, vague and does not define "involvedness". The answers that exist at the moment also show this. I'm trying to **clarify** your quesiton so it can be answered!

Comment: Okay, so the object *doesn't* have to be animate.

Comment: How about: "She drew / painted / sculpted me". That is, she created an artwork representing me. I do not have to be present when she does that (your criterion from yesterday's comment). I do not necessarily receive anything (your criterion from today). Yet, "me" is a direct object.

Comment: @RichardZ I think it depends on whether you think that 'me' is not involved in the action of those verbs at all. Cf. "She drew a picture of me."

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. The definition of "involvedness" is what I'm trying to elucidate. According to the criteria you provided, "me" seems to be un-involved. So would you agree that "me" is not involved? Or is that not the kind of example you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The indirect object is very much involved: if your mother doesn’t make a sandwich, you don’t get to eat one.

An indirect object is the *[receiver of the action](http://plato.algonquincollege.com/applications/guideToGrammar/?page_id=3357)*: the noun/pronoun to or for whom/which the action is performed. Mom does the work; you enjoy the sandwich. Grammatically, of course, it doesn’t matter if the action is real, supposed, or negated.

> The board gave your **proposal** a thorough review.
>   Will Richard and Monica buy their **daughter** a new car?
>   John never tells his **wife** the truth.

Your proposal gets a review, the daughter may get a car, and John’s wife never gets the truth.

Comment: Note that my example doesn't tell you anything about whether or not I have eaten or even received the sandwich. All it tells you is that Mom intended it for me, which may or may not lead to any event involving 'me'.

Comment: @listeneva: and how is that of any importance? "…it doesn’t matter if the action is real, supposed, or negated.” The ind. obj. is still the receiver of the action. Just because you could feed the sandwich to the dog doesn't matter to the declarative statement that your mother made the sandwich for you.

Comment: Exactly. Your last sentence proves my point: "Mom made me a sandwich" doesn't guarantee that I receive the sandwich from Mom. Then, how could you say that I'm the receiver of the action expressed by the verb 'make' when the dog ate the sandwich? What is it that I received? Nothing. Perhaps you've got a recipient mixed up with a revocable beneficiary.

Comment: @listeneva: So you are contending that _Mom never makes me a sandwich_ and a potentially canine-devoured sandwich are completely different from _Mom made me a sandwich_?. Let me put it this way. The indirect object isn’t about you. It’s about the verb. Whether you actually get a sandwich is controlled by other sentence elements, not the relationship of the verb _make_ to _me_.

Comment: I'm not here to argue with you, but let me just say this. _Mom made me a sandwich_ doesn't entail _me_ eating or even receiving _the sandwich_ any more than _Mom never makes me a sandwich_.

Answer (score 1):

Verbs can refer to many different kinds of concepts. The object of a verb, direct or indirect, does not have to be involved with or affected by an action.

Here is an example: "I hate zucchini noodles". This sentence describes how I feel *about* zucchini noodles. It could be true even if I have never interacted with zucchini noodles since I started hating them.

Another simple example is the verb "want": "I want that sandwich" describes my desire for the sandwich, not some action involving the sandwich.

Another example that is similar to yours, but that clearly involves a direct object is "I helped my parents make dinner by chopping vegetables." Here, the physical action that I am describing is chopping vegetables; "my parents", as the direct object of the verb *help,* refers to the *beneficiary* of my action. I could help my parents in this way without them being involved at all in my vegetable-chopping (e.g. maybe I do it while they're busy doing something else).

Some verbs allow *me* to be used the way you used it in your question, but others don't. The exact meaning of *me* will depend on the specific verb. Other verbs with similar semantics (because they refer at least in part to an action that can be taken in advance of the "intended" recipient actually receiving something) are *bake* (as in "I baked him a cake; it's in my car now") or *send* (as in "I sent them some postcards that should arrive next week").

As a side point, it is debated whether "me" in sentences like the one you describe should be called an "indirect object". This is a traditional term, but in English, "indirect objects" like this are very similar in many ways to "direct objects".

Comment: Thanks. But I think 'hate' and 'want' are stative verbs in your examples, which means they don't mean an 'action' but only a 'state'. In your noodle example, I think 'zucchini noodles' is directly involved in the emotional state of 'hate'. Similarly, 'that sandwich' can be said to be directly involved in the emotional state of 'want'. Also, in your 'my parents' example, 'my parents' are the ones directly being helped. Thus, I would say these might be different from my 'make' example.

Comment: @listeneva: I can see how it's not quite the same. I think that verbs can sometimes refer to a combination of action and emotional state.